# Dividing values with DISTINCTCOUNT does not work in DAX Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

When applying the following code to generate "PostCounter", I get the correct output:

Visualization:
[image: Table and code]

[image: Chart]

**Issue**: I need to divide not by the static "2" value, but by DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(shocks[ID]), which of course is equal to 2, as such:

[image: Pic]

**But**, this generates the wrong numbers, as you can see from the chart:

[image: Pic2]

**Why is DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Shocks[ID]) not = 2 here, and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being evaluated in context. Try something like:

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(shocks[ID]), REMOVEFILTERS())
```